# how to do a same function for multiple button if any of them have been clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code in a specific page , a table with lots of columns that are button type.

```
<TABLE BORDER="2">
<TR>
<TD><FORM METHOD="LINK" id="paging">
<INPUT id="m-4"TYPE="button" VALUE=<?php echo $center-4?>>
</FORM></TD>
<TD><FORM METHOD="LINK" >
<INPUT id="m-3" TYPE="button" VALUE=<?php echo $center-3?>>
</FORM></TD>
```

I select one of the button and do the function that I want and this works,

```
$('#m-4').click(pagenumload);
function pagenumload()
{
 pagenum = $('#m-4').val()-1;
}
```

I want to do the same function ( pagenumload ) to all of the buttons, not only '#m-4' , how should I implement that?, tnx.

Comment: First off, on a slightly unrelated note, please do not ALLCAPS your html tags as if this were the 90's. Personally, it makes it a pain just to read.

Comment: @NickDugger That's pure preference, his style of markup is not wrong.

Comment: @NickDugger - that really takes me back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('input[id^="m-"]').click(pagenumload);
```

This one in particular selects all inputs with `id` attribute value starting with "m-".

Though I highly recommend you add a `classname` to your inputs so you can use the simpler class selector, eg. `$('.myButton')`

Answer (score 1):

Attach the method to a class instead:

```
<TABLE BORDER="2">
<TR>
<TD><FORM METHOD="LINK" id="paging">
<INPUT class="navbutton" id="m-4"TYPE="button" VALUE=<?php echo $center-4?>>
</FORM></TD>
<TD><FORM METHOD="LINK" >
<INPUT class="navbutton" id="m-3" TYPE="button" VALUE=<?php echo $center-3?>>
</FORM></TD>

$('.navbutton').click(function() {
    pagenum = $(this).val()-1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your inputs a class:

```
<INPUT id="m-4" TYPE="button" class="m" VALUE=<?php echo $center-4?>>
...
<INPUT id="m-3" TYPE="button" class="m" VALUE=<?php echo $center-3?>>
```

And then reference them accordingly:

```
$('.m').click(pagenumload);
function pagenumload()
{
    pagenum = $(this).val()-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could given them a common class, or use an input[type='button'] selector:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    // inside here 'this' is the button that was clicked
});
```